# Intersection of a line and a polynomial in projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm having trouble understanding the solution to the following problem (taken from the book "*Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach*"):

> Let $P(x,y,z)$ be a homogenous polynomial and $l = ax + by + cz$ be a linear polynomial. Now suppose $(x_0 : y_0 : z_0) \in V(P) \cap V(l)$. Show that $(x_0 : z_0)$ is a root of the homogeneous polynomial $P(x, ax + cz,z)$ and that $y_0 = ax_0 + cz_0$.

Now, working over $\mathbb{CP}^2$ I can assume that $b = -1$ and we know that $P(x_0, y_0, z_0) = 0$ and $ax_0 + by_0 + cz_0 =0$. So from here we deduce that:
$$ax_0 - y_0 + cz_0 = 0 \implies y_0 = ax_0 + cz_0 $$.
Then substituting for $y_0$ we also obtain that $P(x_0, ax_0 + cz_0, z_0) = 0$.
However, I don't quite understand how one can show that $(x_0 : z_0)$ is a root of this polynomial.

Comment: @EricTowers well it was my understanding that if $(x_0 : y_0 : z_0) \in V(P)$, the vanishing set of $P(x,y,z)$, then it must be the case $P(x_0, y_0, z_0)=0$, or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: No, I am.  (Too early here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the clue is that $P(x,ax+cz,z)$ is a polynomial on $K[X:Z]$, lets call it $F$, that brings $[x_0:z_0]$ to $P(x_0,ax_0+cz_0,z_0)$ and you have just proof that $P(x_0,ax_0+cz_0,z_0)=0$ So you Have that, by definition of $F$, $[x_0:z_0]$ is a root because $F(x_0:z_0)=P(x_0,ax_0+cz_0,z_0)=0$

What is obviously not true is that $[x_0:z_0]$ Is a root of $P$,this is no sense in fact, due to $P$ is in $K[X,Y,Z]$

Comment: What do you mean by "that brings $[x_0 : z_0]$ to $P(x_0,ax_0+cz_0,z_0)$"?

Comment: I wanted to said that $F[x:y]=P(x,ax+cz,z)$